# How can I split a Python module into several files with interdependencies without hardcoding the package name?

Tags: python

With hardcoding the package name, it could work as follows:

```
$ cat mypackage/__init__.py
from somefunc import somefunc
from someotherfunc import someotherfunc

$ cat mypackage/somefunc.py
import mypackage

def somefunc(recurse):
    print 'enter:', recurse
    if recurse:
        mypackage.someotherfunc()
    print 'leave:', recurse

$ cat mypackage/someotherfunc.py
import mypackage

def someotherfunc():
    mypackage.somefunc(False)
$ python -c 'import mypackage; mypackage.somefunc(True)'
enter: True
enter: False
leave: False
leave: True
```

Now, is it possible to do the same, i.e. define `somefunc` and `someotherfunc` in different files of the same package but without mentioning `mypackage` in the functions when calling the other function?

It also works fine when defining the two functions in the same file.

Comment: Something like `import . as somename` and then call `somename.somefunc` would be nice, but that doesn't work as per [Python's documentation about the import statement](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)

Comment: why do you want this?  what's so terrible about mentioning the module's name in the place that depends on that module?

Comment: @IfLoop: For one thing it feels redundant to use an absolute name to use a member of the current package. And in my specific case I want to rename `mypackage` and thought that reducing the number of `$oldname` first is a nice cleanup and simplifies reviewing the complete patch set.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just import `someotherfunc` in `somefunc` AND `somefunc` in `someotherfunc`?

My bother to import `mypackage` at all?

I cannot see (nor have you provided) a use case for what you are trying to do.

I think you would make [Rube Goldberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) proud.

Comment: Thought 1 doesn't help. Regarding Thought 2, I don't know where you want to check for `__name__`, but I don't see what it would help. Thought 3.1: Yeah, maybe, but doesn't help either, does it? Ditto for 3.2.

Comment: Have you tried your suggestion? I bet you didn't. And yes, the example looks artificial because I broke the much bigger project down to a few small files. I'm not saying the code is excellent as is, or that I really must drop absolute imports. It's just that doing it with absolute imports seems to carry more redundancy than I'm used to with Python.